# Delphi Statictext font colour change without styles

Tags: delphi

I'm wanting to change my StaticText font colour from black to `clBlue`. How can I go about this?

Currently I'm doing

```
StaticText.Font.Color := clBlue;
```

but that is making no difference to the colour.

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TStaticText` control is a wrapper around the Win32 [`STATIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx) control. When themes are enabled, the system ignores the font color that is specified, and uses the color specified by the theme. Other standard system controls behave in this manner too.

If you want to be able to specify the color of the text, you will need to use a different control. For instance, `TLabel`.

Comment: You could also disable theme for a specific control via: `SetWindowTheme(AControl.Handle, ' ', ' ')`

Answer (score 5):

Set the static text `Transparent` property to `False`